# how is the following UNIX command interpreted

Tags: shell

How is this command interpreted:

```
cat file.txt |
```

If no arguments are passed after the pipe, can you explain at the C level why and how a new embedded command line interface is opened?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the end of the command. The shell is waiting for the rest of it. If you force it, you get `Syntax error: end of file unexpected`

Comment: It depends on the shell and on whether it's interactive or not. An sh-derived shell (sh, bash, ksh, zsh) will probably prompt for the rest of the command. A csh-derived shell (csh, tcsh) will immediately report an error "Invalid null command".